# Print statements in triggers causing issues with insert via SQL Alchemy

Tags: python, sql-server, azure, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

Ours is flask app, sql alchemy, sql server based stack. We are seeing a weird issue issue in our production.

While doing an insert operation, we are getting

```
sqlalchemy.orm.exc:ObjectDeletedError
```

In database we see that the entity did not got created. We have a trigger function on our insert which has lot of PRINT statements in it.

Sequence of events -

```
obj = Object()
session.add(obj)
session.commit()
obj.id  # sqlalchemy.orm.exc:ObjectDeletedError
```

Issue is not seen if we remove the PRINT statements.

Whats the co relation of print statements in triggers and sql alchemy? 
Also the issue is not seen in our test envs but only on production.